# kubectl kustomize leaves placeholder lines

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I'm trying to use Kustomize but as a result I have wrong placeholder lines.

I have `base/deployment.yaml` like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER
          name: CONTAINER_NAME_PLACEHOLDER
```

And also `base/kustomization.yaml`:

```
resources:
  - deployment.yaml
```

And also overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml:

```
resources:
  - ../../base
commonLabels:
  app: myname
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - change_container_name.yaml
```

And `overlays/dev/change_container_name.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myname
          image: registry.mycompany.ru/project/app:VERSION
```

And as a result of running `kubectl kustomize ./overlays/dev` i see in my console something like this:

```
...
containers:
      - image: registry.mycompany.ru/project/app:VERSION
        name: myname
        image: IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER #--- unwanted line
        name: CONTAINER_NAME_PLACEHOLDER #--- unwanted line
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to work the way you want: because `containers:` is a list, Kustomize uses the container name to identify which element you want to modify. Because the container name in your patch doesn't match an existing container name, you are *adding a new container* to the deployment. That's why you end up with:

```
      containers:
      - image: registry.mycompany.ru/project/app:VERSION
        name: myname
      - image: IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER
        name: CONTAINER_NAME_PLACEHOLDER
```

I'm not sure what your motivation is here, but if you really want to modify the name of an existing container you can do that using a jsonpatch patch instead of a strategic merge patch. The patch might look like this:

```
- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/name
  value: myname
```

And I would use it in a kustomization file like this:

```
resources:
  - ../../base

commonLabels:
  app: myname

patches:
  - path: change_container_name.yaml
    target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: app
```

Given your examples, this would produce the following output:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myname
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myname
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myname
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER
        name: myname
```

You could do the same thing with the image name, but you could *also* use an [image transformer](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/transformerconfigs/README.md#images-transformer):

```
resources:
  - ../../base
commonLabels:
  app: myname

patches:
  - path: change_container_name.yaml
    target:
      kind: Deployment
      name: app

images:
  - name: IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER
    newName: registry.mycompany.ru/project/app
    newTag: VERSION
```

Which gets us:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myname
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myname
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myname
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: registry.mycompany.ru/project/app:VERSION
        name: myname
```